# Recommended type/file structure with Cofoundry cms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, cofoundry

when I make a new cofoundry project (dotnet new cofoundry-web -n ExampleApp) basic files/folders like e.g. Views, Properties, Bin. this is my first time working with a CMS and especially with DotNet Core. I've only build DotNet projects with EF Core and web/api and from my internship I learnt a file structure with that. but I am not confident if CoFoundry is using EFCore and how i should implement a file structure ore use it as I always did with other non CMS projects.

what I've learned from the internship was that I have a folder and in that, we have a:
Appname.sln (i am on Linux so a solution file isn't that important.)
Solution Folder with the actual webproject (MyApi)
Class library called `MyApi.Entities,`
Class library called `MyApi.Business`,
Class library called `MyApi.Common`,
Class library called `MyApi.Security`,
Class library called `MyApi.UnitTests`

it depends on what type of project but this was the rough line of each project. Should I follow this the same way with a Cofoundry CMS project or not? Because I can not see the wood for the trees at this point.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cofoundry does not impose any specific file structure on you, unless you want to take advantage of Cofoundry specific features such as page templates or block types.

I would clone some of the [sample applications](https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/getting-started/sample-projects) and have a look at the structure. The [SimpleSite sample](https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/Cofoundry.Samples.SimpleSite) follows a fairly normal MVC application route, with the "Cofoundry" folder only used for Cofoundry specific code. The [SPA Site sample](https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/Cofoundry.Samples.SPASite) is more advance and has a separate project for code and includes a custom EF Core DbContext, but this is quite opinionated and serves only as an example of what's possible.

If you're comfortable organizing your project in a specific way then you should be able to do that. There's some [EF Tools](https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/framework/entity-framework-and-dbcontext-tools) available, but again you only need to use them if you find them useful.

The only thing I would be wary of is that Cofoundry manages the installation of it's database schema itself, so if you use EF migrations you'll need to make sure it only includes your tables.